# Finding power of the given test

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing

Given that $X$ is a single observation from $f(x;\theta)=(2\theta x+1-\theta)I_{[0,1]}(x)$ where $-1\leq \theta \leq 1.$

The objective is to test the hypothesis $H_0:\theta\leq0$ Vs $H_1:\theta>0$ where $H_0$ is rejected when $X>\frac{1}{2}$.

I am a little confused about finding the power of the test. Power of this test is given as $1-\beta$, where $\beta=P(Accept\:H_0\:|\:H_1)$. Hence, $1-\beta=P(Reject\:H_0\:|\:H_1)$ i.e. $P(X>\frac{1}{2})$ under $H_1$.

Thus, $P(X>\frac{1}{2})=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}f(x;\theta)dx=\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}(2\theta x+1-\theta)dx=(\theta x^2+x-\theta x)|_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}=1-\frac{1}{4}[2-\theta]$.

Obviously this is a function of $\theta$ since under $H_1$, $\theta >0$ is unknown.

Now in general in hypothesis testing what we do is, we fix the size of the test i.e we fix $P(Reject\:H_0\:|\:H_0)$ and then maximize the power function $1-\beta$ or equivalently minimize $\beta$.

So if we maximize the power function obtained above for $-1\leq\theta \leq 1$, we obtain $(1-\frac{1}{4})=\frac{3}{4}$.

Is that correct ?

Also, can anyone provide a hint for finding a test for the given hypothesis that minimizes the largest of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. (For any general distribution).

$H_0:\theta = \theta_1$ Vs $H_1:\theta = \theta_2$

Are we supposed to follow that same technique i.e. fixing $\alpha$ first and then handling $\beta$ ? Or something else ?

Comment: In general, one indeed fixes $\alpha$ first and then finds a rejection rule such that the rejection probability of the test is $\alpha$ when the null is true. In this exercise (please add the self-study tag!), the rejection rule has been decided upon ($X>1/2$), based on considerations that are not given.

Comment: Also, in general, with only one test statistic one cannot really maximize power - you could find the best (in the sense of most powerful) test in a class of, for example, level-$\alpha$ tests